# Why does God use an army of Angels to fight against evil when he could do it himself?

Tags: nature-of-god, satan, angels, demons

Many places in the Bible talk about a heavenly host or army of angels. Why does God use an army to fight against devil and evil spirits, when he is the powerful creator? Matthew 19:26 says, all things are possible with God. It really makes me to think "*are Devils equal to God in power*"?.

Here are a few examples that speak about the army of God (Angels):

Psalm 35:5-6, Matthew 13:41, II Kings 6:14-17, Revelation 12:7-8

Comment: Why do you think God *needs* an army of angels?

Comment: @curiousdannii Those examples I attached might answer your question. Your comment and my questions are mostly identical. Ans is: In many places I see angels are used to fight against enemy ex:Isaiah 37:36. Your down vote to questions, (here no appropriate comments), simply makes no sense.

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous, and it is rude to guess who has voted. As to those verses, none of them suggest God needs angels, only that he has them. I don't think any Christians would think that God needs them.

Comment: @curiousdannii I am very sorry and apology for misusing your name & reputation (If it was not you). I think my question was clear: Why God uses Army of angels to destroy /fight against what he created. I already mentioned Matthew 19:26. Why this Angel character comes in picture.

Comment: Why does God *choose to use* angels is a much better question than why does God *need/require* them (especially when most Christians would say he doesn't need them.) I'd encourage you to [edit] this and focus only on the first one.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks for editing the question more precisely & clearly.

Comment: The scriptures rarely draw a distinction between God acting "Himself" and acting through angels. In fact, many things which the Old Testament declares were done by God, in the NT we read were performed through angels. Not merely "fighting against evil" but, e.g. the giving of the Mosaic Law, and God revealing His Glory to Moses. Even in the NT, the distinction is only made in order to contrast His former interactions with man through angels, with His interaction with man through His Son.

Comment: @JoachinJoseph Mystery + God fights fair + it is God who guarantees the victory and it is by him the winning is achieved.

Answer (score 4):

God graciously allows the Angels to fight the battles with the Devil and his demons. God is omniscient and already knows who will be successful in every battle between The Arch Angel Michael and Satan and his rebellious Angels.

If God himself were to oppose Satan it would not be a battle since God is omnipotent. There are other factors which need be considered also, God does not unleash all of his Angels against them either. We know this because only one third of the Angels rebelled with Satan.

> Revelation 12:4 KJV  And his tail drew the third part of the stars of heaven, and did cast them to the earth: and the dragon stood before the woman which was ready to be delivered, for to devour her child as soon as it was born.

With a two to one advantage it would have been a short war.

So it seems that God is even gracious to his enemies, which may give some insight to:

> Matthew 5:43 and 44 KJV have heard that it hath been said, Thou shalt love thy neighbour, and hate thine enemy. But I say unto you, Love your enemies, bless them that curse you, do good to them that hate you, and pray for them which despitefully use you, and persecute you;

and also:

> Luke 10:19  Behold, I give unto you power to tread on serpents and scorpions, and over all the power of the enemy: and nothing shall by any means hurt you.

Unless I am mistaken when Jesus refers to **the enemy** he is referring to the Devil.

Comment: The question reminded me of a quote from *At the Back of the North Wind*: "It is not good at all—mind that
Diamond—to do everything for those you love, and not give them a share in the doing.  It is not kind.  It's making too much of yourself, my child." Also, a father rejoices in seeing his children actively displaying his good character and working in the family business. This sharing of work and character is part of familial love (among siblings and between parents and children).

Comment: The negative of this dignity and love in work is expressed in Edna St. Vincent Millay's "The Suicide": "Better a perilous journey overseas/Away from thee, than this, the life I lead,/To sit all day in the sunshine like a weed/That grows to naught,—I love thee more than they/Who serve thee most; yet serve thee in no way./Father, I beg of thee a little task/To dignify my days,—’tis all I ask/Forever, but forever, this denied,/I perish.”

Comment: "A third part", does not necessarily mean an exact third. Nothing says the three parts were all the same size.

Comment: @ShemSeger what else can a third part mean but one third?

Comment: Suppose the hosts of heaven were divided into three parts; pacifists, proponents, and opponents. There could have been uneven numbers in each part. The Devil could have been outnumbered by more than just 2-1, it could have been 3-1, or 5-1, maybe even 1-1 if there were a part that chose not to fight at all.

Comment: @Bye notice also that the King James Version of the verse translates τὸ τρίτον as *the* third, not *a* third, and the literal translation of τρίτον is *thirdly*.

Comment: @ShemSeger this may be the dumbest arguments I have ever been in, and it makes absolutely no difference to the long run so this will be my last post.

Comment: Independent catholic idea: as I know, the "ordinary" angels don't have free will. Thus, they can be considered as "God's hand" in this fight. Thus, really God is fighting.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try an LDS answer.

What is this war we are talking about?

Let's look into premortal life:

Abraham 3:22-28

> 22 Now the Lord had shown unto me, Abraham, the intelligences that
>   were organized before the world was; and among all these there were
>   many of the noble and great ones;
>
> 23 And God saw these souls that they were good, and he stood in the
>   midst of them, and he said: These I will make my rulers; for he stood
>   among those that were spirits, and he saw that they were good; and he
>   said unto me: Abraham, thou art one of them; thou wast chosen before
>   thou wast born.
>
> 24 And there stood one among them that was like unto God, and he said
>   unto those who were with him: We will go down, for there is space
>   there, and we will take of these materials, and we will make an earth
>   whereon these may dwell;
>
> 25 And we will prove them herewith, to see if they will do all things
>   whatsoever the Lord their God shall command them;
>
> 26 And they who keep their first estate shall be added upon; and they
>   who keep not their first estate shall not have glory in the same
>   kingdom with those who keep their first estate; and they who keep
>   their second estate shall have glory added upon their heads for ever
>   and ever.
>
> 27 And the Lord said: Whom shall I send? And one answered like unto
>   the Son of Man: Here am I, send me. And another answered and said:
>   Here am I, send me. And the Lord said: I will send the first.
>
> 28 And the second was angry, and kept not his first estate; and, at
>   that day, many followed after him.

I guess this is not complete without also citing

Moses 4:1-3

> 1 And I, the Lord God, spake unto Moses, saying: That Satan, whom
>   thou hast commanded in the name of mine Only Begotten, is the same
>   which was from the beginning, and he came before me, saying—Behold,
>   here am I, send me, I will be thy son, and I will redeem all mankind,
>   that one soul shall not be lost, and surely I will do it; wherefore
>   give me thine honor.
>
> 2 But, behold, my Beloved Son, which was my Beloved and Chosen from
>   the beginning, said unto me—Father, thy will be done, and the glory be
>   thine forever.
>
> 3 Wherefore, because that Satan rebelled against me, and sought to
>   destroy the agency of man, which I, the Lord God, had given him, and
>   also, that I should give unto him mine own power; by the power of mine
>   Only Begotten, I caused that he should be cast down;

So, the angels were there before the conflict and the angels are us humans. Further, i will cite Gordon B. Hinckley, at that time apostle, and later president of the church:

"The War we are winning", October 1986

> But there is another war that has gone on since before the world was
>   created and which is likely to continue for a long time yet to come.
>   John the Revelator speaks of that struggle:
>
> “And there was war in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against
>   the dragon; and the dragon fought and his angels,
>
> “And prevailed not; neither was their place found any more in heaven.
>
> “And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the
>   Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was cast out
>   into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him” (Rev. 12:7–9).
>
> That war, so bitter, so intense, has gone on, and it has never ceased.
>   It is the war between truth and error, between agency and compulsion,
>   between the followers of Christ and those who have denied Him. His
>   enemies have used every stratagem in that conflict. They’ve indulged
>   in lying and deceit. They’ve employed money and wealth. They’ve
>   tricked the minds of men. They’ve murdered and destroyed and engaged
>   in every other unholy and impure practice to thwart the work of
>   Christ.

So,

1. The subject of this war is the alignment of its very soldiers, us
2. The only way God could possibly, by divine intervention, end this conflict, is by taking away the agency he means to protect, and force everyone to "be good" - that's contrary to his goals
3. Also, on a side note, the fact that there is this war means everyone eventually has to pick sides, as at least one side is constantly trying to influence them. This means people can choose good over evil.

Comment: The only part of the question that addresses the OP's question is precisely the part that is unsourced.  I'd love a good LDS answer, but this isn't it.

Comment: @AffableGeek How can i improve it? Is sources enough or did i just plain miss the point of the question?

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question.  That said, I think you're on to something in the last paragraph - if you could source it and develop it more.

Comment: @AffableGeek is this better?

Comment: Suddenly your answer is a bit source-heavy. Sources should be used as a supplement for a statement, not as the main body of your answer. I think people prefer to read a summery of verses first, then if they choose they can check the source of your summary, otherwise they'll just skim over the scriptures down to your conclusion.

Comment: @kutschkem Yes :) And +1.  If you could identify the LDS perspective explicitly, that would also be helpful. And, I disagree with Shem.  I think you quoted the LDS Scriptures well.

Comment: @AffableGeek i'm not sure what you mean by "identify the LDS perspective explicitly"

Answer (score 2):

**An indirect answer to your question:**

In Genesis 1 God works at creating order out of chaos. He starts the process of dividing organizing. As creation draws to a close (after much of the work is done) He gives man authority and a mandate to continue this orderly work of "subduing" a small portion of creation, namely the earth. With God as the ultimate source of man's strength, knowledge, ability, all these attributes being needed by man to further subdue, God in essence is still at work through / with the man. However, He is giving humanity the opportunity to work with Him, and thus learn and grow.

This template of God working through man repeats itself in the work of salvation, Christ doing most of the work, and we through the Spirit's help continue with the finishing touches. 1 Cor 3:9

As He has called us to participate with Him in His work, so the angels on a different plain of existence have been invited to participate as well, with the power, strength and intellect that He ultimately supplies. Col 1:16-17;20 It is not out of impotence that He needs our help or the angels cooperation, more out of desire; a desire for relationship as mirrored in Christ's desire. John 17:22-24. The opportunity to work with God brings us closer to Him, something He desires.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that God comes with an army of angels represents unanimous agreement in God's justice in His treatment of sin. God desires His creations to be His co-workers, serving Him with intelligent appreciation of His love and justice, not in fear and doubt of His decisions.

In reality it is hardly a battle with these angels reflecting the glory of God, with countenances as lighting and robes as white as snow (Matthew 28:2). If a man can cast out demons in the name of God (Mark 16:17), how much more can an angel? If anything these battles represent God's army standing in unity against the ideologies and accusations of Satan and his legion, knowing them for the lies that they are.

Answer (score 0):

God is about wrong and right and the struggle between them. We assume God is almighty, but maybe he needs some faith himself. Would you fight for man if they stand lazy on the side expecting you to take care of things. The battle between good and evil are the torments of man, not of God.

Answer (score -2):

God uses angels for this heavenly battle because he is in his rest day, the seventh creative day, which he ordained as holly and a sabbath. So his angels have carried out his work. He couldn't break his own law that he expected man to follow.

Comment: Please explain what the basis for these ideas are. What law are you talking about? Where does the Bible describe God *ordaining* the seventh day of Genesis 2?

Comment: Gen 2 vs 1 to 3. Gods rest day. God blessed the seventh day and made it holy. To me it's why he gave mankind a sabbath day on the seventh day, following the same pattern. Just how I see it. Fits the pattern because God is in his seventh sabbath rest day.